# How to complete wudu while not being circumcised?

Tags: wudu, circumcision

I am not circumcised and I have just converted. I am willing to become circumcised, but my wife wants me to wait a year to ensure that I am still devoted to Allah(SWT). How do I complete wudu with this in mind?

Comment: I'm a revert (2 years), and am not circumcised. It makes no difference to Wudu as Wudu doesn't cover that part of the body. For Ghusl, just make sure to pull the skin back.

Comment: What is the relation between circumcision and wudu' you are referring to? Circumcision is a sunnah for men (not mandatory), while wudu' is mandatory to be able to pray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I had a long answer to this and I mistakenly deleted it. Are you taking about wudu or ghusl (full shower). I think you are talking about the ghusl as in with wudu your private parts are not involved. As the other person mentioned, just pull back your foreskin as much as you can so that water reaches it when you are washing. Also, there is not a consensus among scholars regarding whether circumcision is obligatory or not. Some say it is and some say it is a highly recommended sunnah. But not being circumcised does not affect the status of your Islam.

Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, as a new Muslim it is essential to learn about tahara (purification). I suggest Fiqh Us Sunnah by Sayyid Sabiq Volume 1 and the section on purification. See: https://www.thebcma.com/upload/pdf/islamicstudies/Textbooks/Saabiq-Fiqh-us-Sunnah.pdf